# BackgroundWorker creating excel, need to stylize according to odd/even register

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel, backgroundworker

I have experience on developing .net web apps for long time, but today I was asked to create a windows forms app to create excel based on some data from database and I am not that expert on windows forms.

Its done and working. I added a progress bar using background worker so the program could keep responding and now I would like to change the bgcolor for the row based on its OrderId.

I added the following:

```
backgroundColor = backgroundColor == Color.White ? Color.WhiteSmoke : Color.White;
```

This line of code is right bellow my order foreach, my orders may have many payments and so on, so it would be like many lines on the excel for just one order.

Without the BackgroundWorker everything works just like I intended, but, adding it will mess with everything because as it is in a thread something weird happens.

I hope I made myself pretty clear and hope also to find an answer for this 'problem'.

Below is the code for the backgroundworker, inside this CreateExcel method there is a foreach on orders, but backgroundworker is threaded and my logic for coloring bgcolor for each distinct order is not working...

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Util.CreateExcel(_orders, _fileName, sender as BackgroundWorker, e);
}
```

I tried posting some images, but I need more reputation for this.

The result desired was something like 'zebra', each order with a different bgcolor. Without the backgroudworker this works fine, but with it the result is weird, some orders have the same bgcolor as others and some orders are fine.

Comment: "Something weird happens" isn't enough. What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: Im terrible sorry.... the problem is that the rows are colored wrongly, like orderid 1 should be white both lines and only 1 is white, the other is gray. I would like to make something like odd/even coloring the bgcolor for each order on the excel.

Comment: Can you provide a the thread code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be having a race condition in the color switching code:

```
backgroundColor = backgroundColor == Color.White ? Color.WhiteSmoke : Color.White;
```

This code is similar to:

```
if( backgroundColor == Color.White )
      backgroundColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
else
      backgroundColor = Color.White;
```

Two, or more, threads may walk **simultaneously** through **IF code** and its condition, so there you may have two threads testing and realizing that the background is now White in exactly same time, which is going to produce two WhiteSmoke rows.

The way to solve this is allowing only one thread to execute this block, exclusively, through locking on a shared object (in a field, for example):

```
lock(syncLock)
{
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor == Color.White ? Color.WhiteSmoke : Color.White;
}
```